# Macbook Pro Retina 2015 Wifi problems on Kali

Tags: networking, wifi, osx, kali-linux, broadcom

I have successfully installed Kali 2.0 on my Macbook Pro retina 2015 model running El Cap via dual boot. I do have some experience with Ubuntu etc, and thought I'd try Kali for multiple reasons.

Now, I thought everything worked perfectly, until I noticed there was no WiFi icon in the menu bar. Well, no problem I thought initially. I just grabbed an ethernet cable and connected to my home network without problems. I downloaded the appropriate driver for my network adapter, the Broadcom 4360. However, when I attempted to install the package, the terminal spat out the error message that the package dkms was not installed. Okay great, that can also be installed manually I thought. After trying that, I got yet another error module init tools not installed. Then I figured that this is not just a problem with my Broadcom thingy, but perhaps with my Kali install.

Things I tried:

- Apt-get update, which also spat out errors, mostly 404 not found etc.
- Reinstall headers, also errors (unable to locate headers for kali_4.0.0 etc.)
- followed among others this link: http://samiux.blogspot.nl/2014/02/howto-kali-linux-106-on-macbook-air-mid.html?m=1

Error file is here, I believe the most pressing error is the last one (they are separated by !!!!'s): http://www.megafileupload.com/egdH/errors.

Comment: Please post the exact error messages you're getting. Don't just say "there are errors"; these errors are crucial in figuring out what's going wrong. We don't have a crystal ball.

Comment: @WouterVerhelst I added them, really hope you can help me :)

Comment: Dayum, I fixed it. Well, I don't know what I did differently this time, but it's working now. Thanks for taking the time y'all.